# Template mechanism for web tier files

Tags: java, web-applications, jsp, code-generation

What is the most easy to way invoke a template for web tier files e.g. jsp, xhtml etc? Does any ide comes with such a template feature that I can select a field for a java bean and it will generate the form element of type `<input>`, or `<radio>` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netbeans has a [JSF/Facelets CRUD generator](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JSFCrudGeneratorIn6.1) which you can generate based on JPA entities. Those JPA entities in turn can be generated from an existing database table model.

Eclipse (for Java EE with WTP/Dali) can also autogenerate JPA entities, but not JSF/Facelets CRUD screens.

Comment: @javaguy: the last paragraph is about Eclipse.